# mysqli prepared statements dates and between clause

Tags: mysql, sql, prepared-statement

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT vin FROM jobs WHERE out between ? and ?");
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $startday, $endday);


        $startday = '2013-01-01';
        $endday = '2013-12-31';

        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        $stmt->bind_result($vin);
echo $vin;
```

the code above shoots out this error the query work if i remove the between part of the statment. i tried enclosing the column name in brackets but that kills the query too so i had to remove them. seems the problem is with the between clause i just might not know how to use it. help please

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not on the `BETWEEN` clause but theuse of reserved keyword `OUT` as your column name. There are two ways to keep this work,

One is by wrapping it with backticks,

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT vin FROM jobs WHERE `out` between ? and ?");
```

and the other is by supplying an `ALIAS` on the table, and using it with the column name.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT vin FROM jobs a WHERE a.out between ? and ?");
```

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)